# Make multiple asynchronous calls and do something when they are completed

Tags: asynchronous, coding-style

I have run into this problem across multiple programming languages and I was just wondering what the best way to handle it is.

I have three method calls that fire off asynchronously.  Each one has a callback.  I want to do something only when all three callbacks have completed.

What is the best way to code this?  I usually end up with all these public bool flags and as you add more calls the code gets more convoluted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from C#, I would probably use [`WaitHandle.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx). You can create an array of [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) objects (one for each task to be completed), and pass that array to `WaitAll`. The threaded tasks will get one ManualResetEvent object each, and call the `Set` method when they are ready. `WaitAll` will block the calling thread until all tasks are done. I'll give a C# code example:

```
private void SpawnWorkers()
{
    ManualResetEvent[] resetEvents = new[] {
            new ManualResetEvent(false), 
            new ManualResetEvent(false)
        };

    // spawn the workers from a separate thread, so that
    // the WaitAll call does not block the main thread
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Worker1, resetEvents[0]);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Worker2, resetEvents[1]);
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents);
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(AllTasksAreDone));

    });
}
private void AllTasksAreDone()
{
    // OK, all are done, act accordingly
}

private void Worker1(object state)
{
    // do work, and then signal the waiting thread
    ((ManualResetEvent) state).Set();
}

private void Worker2(object state)
{
    // do work, and then signal the waiting thread
    ((ManualResetEvent)state).Set();
}
```

Note that the `AllTasksAreDone` method will execute on the thread pool thread that was used to spawn the workers, and not on the main thread... I assume that many other languages have similar constructs.

Comment: What context are we in when calling this.BeginInvoke? What is 'this'?

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want to wait for **all** to finish:

1. Create volatile counter
2. Synchronize access to counter
3. Increase counter on start
4. Decrease on callback fired
5. Wait for counter to reach 0

Answer (score 0):

Use a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

Answer (score 0):

Futures are very easy to use. Futures look like normal functions, except that they execute asynch.

The classes:

```
public struct FutureResult<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public Exception Error;
}
public class Future<T>
{
    public delegate R FutureDelegate<R>();
    public Future(FutureDelegate<T> del)
    {
        _del = del;
        _result = del.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
    private FutureDelegate<T> _del;
    private IAsyncResult _result;
    private T _persistedValue;
    private bool _hasValue = false;
    private T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_hasValue)
            {
                if (!_result.IsCompleted)
                    _result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                _persistedValue = _del.EndInvoke(_result);
                _hasValue = true;
            }
            return _persistedValue;
        }
    }
    public static implicit operator T(Future<T> f)
    {
        return f.Value;
    }
}
```

Here I use futures to simulate a deadlock:

```
        void SimulateDeadlock()
        {
            Future> deadlockFuture1 = new Future>(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    new SystemData(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
                        .SimulateDeadlock1(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2));
                    return new FutureResult { Value = true };
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return new FutureResult { Value = false, Error = ex };
                }
            });
            Future> deadlockFuture2 = new Future>(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    new SystemData(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
                        .SimulateDeadlock2(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2));
                    return new FutureResult { Value = true };
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return new FutureResult { Value = false, Error = ex };
                }
            });
            FutureResult result1 = deadlockFuture1;
            FutureResult result2 = deadlockFuture2;
            if (result1.Error != null)
            {
                if (result1.Error is SqlException && ((SqlException)result1.Error).Number == 1205)
                    Console.WriteLine("Deadlock!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result1.Error.ToString());
            }
            else if (result2.Error != null)
            {
                if (result2.Error is SqlException && ((SqlException)result2.Error).Number == 1205)
                    Console.WriteLine("Deadlock!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result2.Error.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: some of the classes are missing from this example

Answer (score 0):

For those using JavaScript, consider using the pattern discussed at this Stackoverflow question:
[javascript: execute a bunch of asynchronous method with one callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911822/javascript-execute-a-bunch-of-asynchronous-method-with-one-callback)