# Best solution to wait for all ajax callbacks to be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, functional-programming, callback

Imagine we have to sources to be requested by ajax. I want to perform some actions when all callbacks are triggered. How this can be done besides this approach:

```
(function($){
  var sources = ['http://source1.com', 'http://source2.com'],
  guard = 0, 
  someHandler = function() { 
    if (guard != sources.length) { return; }
    //do some actions
  };

  for (var idx in sources) {
    $.getJSON(sources[idx], function(){ guard++; someHandler(); })
  }
})(jQuery)
```

What I don't like here is that in this case I can't handle response failing (eg. I can't set timeout for response to come) and overall approach (I suppose there should be a way to use more power of functional programming here)

Any ideas?

Regards!

**UPD:** Thanks for solution with chaining callbacks. I found a good approach [here](http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/#comment-24910):. this is what was proposed in comments:

```
(function hidenext(jq){
    jq.eq(0).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        (jq=jq.slice(1)).length && hidenext(jq);
    });
})($('div#bodyContent a'))
```

With a little bit of tweaking it can wait for the last callback.

*Now I want to handle properly long running requests.* Any clues?

Comment: This has been asked before, but instead of XHR, it was a series of DOM events.  I also can't remember the name of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could 'cascade' the downloads, so the callback of the first getJSON triggers download from the next source, and so on? Then in the last callback you have no sources left and can call your 'done' function.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea! I'll try that and be back. But still a problem with failing response...

Comment: @glaz666: Why can't you set a timeout or define an error callback that handles the error?

Comment: How do I set timeout? :) Error call back is ok

Comment: @glaz666: getJSON is just a shorthand method for $ajax. Use $.ajax() and pass dataType='json' and you can set timeout there (details at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Comment: This basically just makes the calls synchronous, losing the efficiency of async loading.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [javascript: execute a bunch of asynchronous method with one callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911822/javascript-execute-a-bunch-of-asynchronous-method-with-one-callback/2911891#2911891)

```
function createCallback(limit, fn){
    var finishedCalls = 0;
    return function(){
        if (++finishedCalls == limit){
             fn();
        }
    };
}


var callback = createCallback(4, function(){
    alert("woot!");
});


async1(callback);
async2(callback);
async3(callback);
async4(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use $.ajax with "async: false" in options and/or use proper callbacks (beforeSend, error, dataFilter, success and complete).

Comment: `async: false` will freeze the browser UI while the requests are being made.

Comment: async:false - can be an option, thanks. But in case of 'success' or 'complete', it won't work as it will be the same with jQuery

Comment: I really recommend to not use async: false, the user experience is never too good with those type of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong - but the rule is: serialization of AJAX - one at a time
So you HAVE to chain it - each response (call back function) must submit the next one in turn

*.onreadystatechange will give you control (a function that is) )when it is ready - here you can submit the next one in turn