# What are the differences between Deferred, Promise and Future in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise, future, deferred

What are the differences between Deferreds, Promises and Futures?
Is there a generally approved theory behind all these three?

Comment: Worth reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg723713

Comment: I have not used them myself but here is a pretty good intro on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises. Although I don't fully understand the use case properly. In a async event driven language like javascript. At first glance I can't see what they offer over callbacks, apart from maybe a cleaner api. I would love it if someone could provide an example use case, and show how these concepts are applied, and why callbacks would be an inefficient solution.  
@duri this has nothing to do with jQuery. Can the jQuery tag be removed please

Comment: @jfriend00 new link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In light of apparent dislike for how I've attempted to answer the OP's question. The literal answer is, a promise is something shared w/ other objects, while a deferred should be kept private. Primarily, a deferred (which generally extends Promise) can resolve itself, while a promise might not be able to do so.

If you're interested in the minutiae, then examine [Promises/A+](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec).

---

So far as I'm aware, the overarching purpose is to improve clarity and loosen coupling through a standardized interface. See [suggested reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx) from @jfriend00:

> Rather than directly passing callbacks to functions, something which
>   can lead to tightly coupled interfaces, using promises allows one to
>   separate concerns for code that is synchronous or asynchronous.

Personally, I've found deferred especially useful when dealing with e.g. templates that are populated by asynchronous requests, loading scripts that have networks of dependencies, and providing user feedback to form data in a non-blocking manner.

Indeed, compare the pure callback form of doing something after loading CodeMirror in JS mode asynchronously (apologies, I've not used jQuery in a **while**):

```
/* assume getScript has signature like: function (path, callback, context) 
   and listens to onload && onreadystatechange */
$(function () {
   getScript('path/to/CodeMirror', getJSMode);

   // onreadystate is not reliable for callback args.
   function getJSMode() {
       getScript('path/to/CodeMirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js', 
           ourAwesomeScript);
   };

   function ourAwesomeScript() {
       console.log("CodeMirror is awesome, but I'm too impatient.");
   };
});
```

To the promises formulated version (again, apologies, I'm not up to date on jQuery):

```
/* Assume getScript returns a promise object */
$(function () {
   $.when(
       getScript('path/to/CodeMirror'),
       getScript('path/to/CodeMirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js')
   ).then(function () {
       console.log("CodeMirror is awesome, but I'm too impatient.");
   });
});
```

Apologies for the semi-pseudo code, but I hope it makes the core idea somewhat clear. Basically, by returning a standardized promise, you can pass the promise around, thus allowing for more clear grouping.

Comment: While this answer might be useful, it does not factually address the question: so-called deferreds are either futures or promises, depending on the implementation.

Comment: @MartinKällman You're right! I hadn't revisited this in a while and have learned a bit. I'll post a separate answer below, but leave this since people seem to have benefited from the usage example.

Comment: @MartinKällman, considered writing a new answer. However, I think the OP actually wanted to know what Promises and Deferreds are for. The answer to his actual question would be, roughly, "deferreds can resolve their-self. AFAIK, the theory behind promises and deferreds comes from [Functional Reactive Programming|http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_Reactive_Programming], which is a technique for flattening callbacks."

Comment: This is just totally wrong and your examples are just as easy to do with callbacks. Promises are not about callback aggregation and decoupling but providing a DSL to write async code like sync code is written. Especially `fn(callback, errback)` is not any more tightly coupled or less useful than `fn().then(callback, errback)` - but that's a wrong way to use promises anyway. I especially hate the cargo cult `$.when` example - there is absolutely no reason you cannot have a `$.when` function that worked with callbacks.

Comment: This does not answer to the question though +1 that I could be able to know what the callback hell is.

Answer (score 149):

These answers, including the selected answer, are good for introducing promises
conceptually, but lacking in specifics of what exactly the differences are in
the terminology that arises when using libraries implementing them (and there
**are** important differences).

Since it is still [an evolving spec](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#open-issues), the answer currently comes from attempting to survey both references (like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)) and implementations (like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)):

- **Deferred**: Never described in popular references,

  <sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)
  [2](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec)
  [3](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#promises)
  [4](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/README.md)</sup>

  but commonly used by implementations as the arbiter of promise resolution (implementing `resolve` and `reject`).

  <sup>[5](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html)
  [6](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
  [7](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)</sup>

  Sometimes deferreds are also promises (implementing `then`),

  <sup>[5](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html)
  [6](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)</sup>

  other times it's seen as more pure to have the Deferred only
  capable of resolution, and forcing the user to access the promise for
  using `then`.

  <sup>[7](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)</sup>
- **Promise**: The most all-encompasing word for the strategy under discussion.

  A proxy object storing the result of a target function whose
  synchronicity we would like to abstract, plus exposing a `then` function
  accepting another target function and returning a new promise.

  <sup>[2](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec)</sup>

  Example from [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A):

  ```
  > asyncComputeTheAnswerToEverything()
      .then(addTwo)
      .then(printResult);
  44
  ```

  Always described in popular references, although never specified as to
  whose responsibility resolution falls to.

  <sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)
  [2](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec)
  [3](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#promises)
  [4](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/README.md)</sup>

  Always present in popular implementations, and never given
  resolution abilites.

  <sup>[5](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html)
  [6](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
  [7](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)</sup>
- **Future**: a seemingly deprecated term found in some popular references

  <sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)</sup>

  and at least one popular implementation,

  <sup>[8](https://github.com/FuturesJS/FuturesJS)</sup>

  but seemingly being phased out of discussion in preference for the term
  'promise'

  <sup>[3](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#promises)</sup>

  and not always mentioned in popular introductions to the topic.

  <sup>[9](http://books.google.com/books?id=0Fr_lxPGM6QC&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

  However, at least one library uses the term generically for abstracting
  synchronicity and error handling, while not providing `then` functionality.

  <sup>[10](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngScenario/Future.js)</sup>

  It's unclear if avoiding the term 'promise' was intentional, but probably a
  good choice since promises are built around 'thenables.'

  <sup>[2](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec)</sup>

#### References

1. [Wikipedia on Promises & Futures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)
2. [Promises/A+ spec](http://promisesaplus.com/)
3. [DOM Standard on Promises](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#promises)
4. [DOM Standard Promises Spec WIP](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/README.md)
5. [DOJO Toolkit Deferreds](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html)
6. [jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
7. [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)
8. [FutureJS](https://github.com/FuturesJS/FuturesJS)
9. [Functional Javascript section on Promises](http://books.google.com/books?id=0Fr_lxPGM6QC&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q&f=false)
10. [Futures in AngularJS Integration Testing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngScenario/Future.js)

#### Misc potentially confusing things

- [Difference between Promises/A and Promises/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/differences-from-promises-a)

  (TL;DR, Promises/A+ mostly resolves ambiguities in Promises/A)

Comment: To add a bit more clarification on the term "Future" – futures have a long history across many programming languages dating back to the mid-80s. And the term is still in wide use today, in particular on the JVM. JavaScript seems to have chosen to use the term "Promise" to mean something similar to what Java means by "Future". Scala separates the same concept into a "Future" and "Promise" to refer to "read" handle and the "write" handle of what JavaScript programmers call a Promise.

Comment: And of course Microsoft had to come up with their own term for it, so in C# they're called `Task`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The C# Task class was in production before JS promises were even suggested in a spec draft, at least.

Comment: @TylerH Promises as a concept are much older than Javascript. However the term "Task" to refer to a Promise was, as far as I know, new in C#. Microsoft has a long history of renaming common programming terms in their languages/libraries.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yes but we're not talking about the English word promise, but the implementation. There are countless synonyms for most words; complaining one spec author chose one vs another spec author choosing a different one is silly.

Comment: @TylerH No, I am taking about the programming concept, not the general English word. Promises in programming were invented in the 1970's, Javascript/C# were created in the 90's

Answer (score 73):

What really made it all click for me was [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/callbacks-promises-and-coroutines-oh-my-the-evolution-of-asynchronicity-in-javascript) by Domenic Denicola.

In a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/3889970), he gave the description I like most, it's very concise:

> *The point of promises is to give us back functional composition and error bubbling in the async world.*

In other word, promises are a way that lets us write *asynchronous* code that is almost as easy to write as if it was *synchronous*.

Consider this example, with promises:

```
getTweetsFor("domenic") // promise-returning async function
    .then(function (tweets) {
        var shortUrls = parseTweetsForUrls(tweets);
        var mostRecentShortUrl = shortUrls[0];
        return expandUrlUsingTwitterApi(mostRecentShortUrl); // promise-returning async function
    })
    .then(doHttpRequest) // promise-returning async function
    .then(
        function (responseBody) {
            console.log("Most recent link text:", responseBody);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.error("Error with the twitterverse:", error);
        }
    );
```

It works as if you were writing this synchronous code:

```
try {
    var tweets = getTweetsFor("domenic"); // blocking
    var shortUrls = parseTweetsForUrls(tweets);
    var mostRecentShortUrl = shortUrls[0];
    var responseBody = doHttpRequest(expandUrlUsingTwitterApi(mostRecentShortUrl)); // blocking x 2
    console.log("Most recent link text:", responseBody);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with the twitterverse: ", error);
}
```

(If this still sounds complicated, watch that presentation!)

Regarding Deferred, it's a way to `.resolve()` or `.reject()` promises. In the [Promises/B](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/B) spec, it is called `.defer()`. In jQuery, it's `$.Deferred()`.

Please note that, as far as I know, the Promise implementation in jQuery is broken (see that gist), at least as of jQuery 1.8.2.
It supposedly implements [Promises/A thenables](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), but you don't get the correct error handling you should, in the sense that the whole "async try/catch" functionality won't work. 
Which is a pity, because having a "try/catch" with async code is utterly cool.

If you are going to use Promises (you should try them out with your own code!), use [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). The jQuery version is just some callback aggregator for writing cleaner jQuery code, but misses the point.

Regarding Future, I have no idea, I haven't seen that in any API.

**Edit:** [Domenic Denicola's youtube talk on Promises](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hf1T_AONQJU) from [@Farm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286588/farm)'s comment below.

A quote from Michael Jackson (yes, *Michael Jackson*) from the video:

> I want you to burn this phrase in your mind: 
>   *A promise is an **asynchronous value***.

This is an excellent description: a promise is like a variable from the future - a first-class reference to something that, at some point, will exist (or happen).

Comment: A great explanation of Futures (now implemented in the DOM!) by a member of the W3 and Chrome core team is to be found here:
http://www.xanthir.com/b4PY0

Comment: @oligofren Thanks for the link, that seems nice! By the way, what a mysteriously annoying favicon lol.

Comment: This answer needs a lot more upvotes. It should be voted higher than the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: Domenic Denicola's youtube talk on Promises : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hf1T_AONQJU

Comment: @Farm Great! I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Here is a link to the [SPECIFIC PART](https://youtu.be/hf1T_AONQJU?t=13m39s) of the above mentioned video on promises by Domenic Denicola.

Comment: For me, the key phrase for understanding deferreds from this post was " Deferred, it's a way to .resolve() or .reject() promises"

Answer (score 34):

A **Promise** represents a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers to an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise of having a value at some point in the future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

The `deferred.promise()` method allows an asynchronous function to prevent other code from interfering with the progress or status of its internal request. The Promise exposes only the Deferred methods needed to attach additional handlers or determine the state (**then, done, fail, always, pipe, progress, state and promise**), but not ones that change the state (**resolve, reject, notify, resolveWith, rejectWith, and notifyWith**).

If target is provided, `deferred.promise()` will attach the methods onto it and then return this object rather than create a new one. This can be useful to attach the Promise behavior to an object that already exists.

If you are creating a Deferred, keep a reference to the Deferred so that it can be resolved or rejected at some point. Return only the Promise object via deferred.promise() so other code can register callbacks or inspect the current state.

> Simply we can say that a **Promise** represents a value that is not yet known where as a **Deferred** represents work that is not yet finished.

---

> [image]

Comment: plus 1 for the chart representation. Bravisimo!! ^_^

Answer (score 25):

- A `promise` represents a value that is not yet known
- A `deferred` represents work that is not yet finished

A promise is a placeholder for a result which is initially unknown while a deferred represents the computation that results in the value.

Reference

- http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics