# Angularjs what is the differences of handling ajax from success/error and promise?

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure where I should handle the response of my ajax request.

There are 2 flavours.

1. handle via success/error callback from $http.
2. handle via then() method from promise result.

Both responds as expected. But, I suppose that there is a 'catch' where to use each one. Google didn't show me the way. And angular.js source code is kinda... cryptic for me.

Notice: My example (1) always responds first and then (2) responds next. I think is just because localhost latency is nearly null and they both are async method.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'ping.php',
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Flavour one success");
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Flavour one error");                       
}).then(function() { 
    console.log("Flavour two success"); }, 
        function() { console.log("Flavour two error");
```

});

Comment: My google [results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127703/asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-vs-deferred-promise) and [another](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)

Comment: @ClydeByrdIII He's not asking about the difference between callbacks and promises. He's asking about the difference between the `success`, `error`, and `then` functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Angular documentation,

> `{HttpPromise}` – Returns a promise object with the standard `then` method
>   and two http specific methods: `success` and `error`. The `then` method
>   takes two arguments: a `success` and an `error` callback which will be
>   called with a response object. The `success` and `error` methods take a
>   single argument - a function that will be called when the request
>   succeeds or fails respectively.

To answer your question, the only difference is that `success` and `error` only take one argument, whereas `then` takes two arguments.

The first will always be invoked before the second, simply because you've listed it in that order, and that's how promises work. If you had listed another `then`, then it would be invoked third.

Answer (score 3):

There are some benefits to using promises over your basic success/error callbacks. One benefit is that you can chain them as described [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#chainingpromises).

> Chaining promises
>   Because calling the then method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises:

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
  return result + 1;
});

// promiseB will be resolved immediately after promiseA is resolved and its value
// will be the result of promiseA incremented by 1`
```

> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs like $http's response interceptors.

You can also combine multiple promises using [$q.all()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#all). This can be really helpful when bootstrapping an application that depends on multiple resources to be loaded before continuing on.

Comment: But don't `success` and `error` return promises as well? (Look at the original post... that's what he's doing.)

Comment: Kind of... $http returns a promise with "two $http specific methods: success and error". http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#generalusage

Comment: @MariusSoutier You can't chain multiple `success` and `error` calls, but you can chain `then` calls FROM a `success` or `error` call.