# JavaScript callback and promise confusion

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to understand a API reference description and I'm having trouble understanding what it means:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray

On the top it says

> 'toArray(callback)  -> Promise'

I know the callback is equivalent to a "Block" but what does it mean to have an arrow sign pointing to "Promise"?

Comment: It says it right there on the page itself - *Returns:
Promise if no callback passed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that the function can either take a callback, or return a `Promise`. As explained in the documentation.

> **Returns:**
>   Promise if no callback passed

So you can either call that function passing a callback:

```
acursor.toArray(anarray => {
  // …
});
```

Or get the result using the returned Promise:

```
acursor
  .toArray()
  .then(anarray => {
    // …
  });
```

Comment: why would i want to use a promise when I can just do get the result on the callback?

Comment: Seem like I'm writing extra code, but doing the same thing.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks

Comment: Do you think this is also valid?  The answer given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244775/what-is-the-difference-between-callback-and-promise?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It’s up to you to use either of the two APIs, they’ll both work and do what you want to achieve.