# When to use promises over callback?

Tags: javascript

I can understand when to use callbacks and when to use promises in real world scenario except callback hell situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041462/node-js-when-to-use-promises-vs-callbacks , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244775/what-is-the-difference-between-callback-and-promise,

Comment: This might help: [When to use Promises vs Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046393/1823841)

Comment: If you're talking about making your own functions to utilize promises or callbacks, then... imo, if it's async, ALWAYS use promises, and if it's not async, then really ask yourself why you would need a callback.