# JQuery and WinJS - Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, winjs, promise

WinJS Promises and JQuery Promises are the same thing?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just search in your favorite search engine for ` JS promises ` [has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801283/what-are-the-differences-between-deferred-promise-and-future-in-javascript?lq=1)

Comment: Their purpose is the same, the work 'a little' different. http://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2012/08/09/promises-jquery-deferred-object-vs-winjs-promise/ Dude, you need to ask a real question and google around a bit before posting here.

Comment: Parse.com uses promises and has some good docs explaining how they work. Hope this helps: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are a programming pattern for dealing with asynchronous operations. The pattern could be applied to other languages, but they are most commonly encountered in JS libraries (like jQuery and WinJS).

Kraig Brockschmidt has a really good blog post about how they work (in general) and in WinJS here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/06/11/all-about-promises-for-windows-store-apps-written-in-javascript.aspx

I've written a blog post comparing jQuery promises and promises in WinJS. The short answer: they're interoperable.
http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/10/jquery-and-winjs-working-together-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: They're not completely compatible, since jQuery has always() and fail() methods.  $.Deferred().reject() doesn't result in a call to the error handler on a WinJS Promise either.

Comment: You can do some of the basics with WinJS and jQuery promises - chaining, joining. I didn't know about $.Deferred().reject(), so thank you!