# HowTo properly test Angular's $http success and error promise with sinon.js?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

HowTo properly test Angular's `$http` `success` and `error` promise with sinon.js? This is what I have so far (all in coffeescript):

#### Service Autobahn

```
drive: (vehicle) ->
  $http.post '/user/signin', vehicle
  .success ((data) ->
    # do stuff
    return data
  ).error
    throw Error (error)
```

#### Controller Streets

```
$scope.drive = (vehicle) ->
    $scope.data = Autobahn.drive(vehicle)
```

#### Unit Test w. Sinon

```
it 'should test $http callbacks', ->
  sinon.stub($scope, 'drive').yieldsTo 'success', callBackMockData
  $scope.drive vehicle, (data) ->
    expect($scope.data).to.be(callBackMockData)
    return
  return
```

#### Result

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '(function(data) {
          return data;
        }).error(function(data) {
          throw Error(error);
        })')
```

Maybe stub is not the correct approach here as I want to really test the controller and service in one go. How can we test Angular's $http promises? The offical documentation uses httpBackEnd failing to provide details on how to test $http's callback chain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$http`'s `success` and `error` promises. `$http` is a promise by itself. Use `.then()`.

See: [Undefinied is not a function when using .success on a function that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521098/undefinied-is-not-a-function-when-using-success-on-a-function-that-returns-a-pr)