# Understanding the example of $.deferred in jQuery documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just trying to demystify how the method `$.Deferred` works in jQuery. I know that its mostly used for AJAX stuff, but I would also like to use this method for non-AJAX stuff. I was reading [the jQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/) on this method and came across the following piece of code:

```
$.fn.bindOnce = function( event, callback ) {
    var element = $( this[ 0 ] ),
        defer = element.data( "bind_once_defer_" + event );

    if ( !defer ) {
        defer = $.Deferred();
        function deferCallback() {
            element.unbind( event, deferCallback );
            defer.resolveWith( this, arguments );
        }
        element.bind( event, deferCallback )
        element.data( "bind_once_defer_" + event , defer );
    }

    return defer.done( callback ).promise(); 
   // what is this piece of code really doing and why is it necessary ? 
};
```

... now if you walk through the code line by line its pretty easy to under whats going on.

The jQuery documentation tells us whats happening line by line , like so :

> - Check if the element already has a deferred attached for the given event
> - if not, create it and make it so it is resolved when the event is fired the first time around
> - then attach the given callback to the deferred and return the promise.

the difficulty I have and the line of however that I cannot understand is below :

```
return defer.done( callback ).promise();
```

I fail to understand the purpose of this line of code and why it is useful and what exactly is the promise method doing in this scenario ?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Can you please take note of [the formatting improvements made to your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31263269/revisions), and apply them going forward? Your questions have a history of being poorly formatted initially, and having to be editing/ improved by editors.

Comment: @Matt Sure , will make note of that ! :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

`promise()` creates a *promise* object for a deferred. The promise object exposes a subset of the methods available on the deferred; which let clients register event handlers to the various events, but **not** modify the deferred itself.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise):

> The promise object provides a subset of the methods of the `Deferred` object (`then`, `done`, `fail`, `always`, `pipe`, `progress`, `state` and `promise`) to prevent users from changing the state of the Deferred.

Therefore,

```
return defer.done( callback ).promise();
```

... is adding the `callback` function to be executed when the deferred (`defer`) resolves, then returns the corresponding promise for the deferred.

You may find the following question useful; [What are the differences between Deferred, Promise and Future in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801283/what-are-the-differences-between-deferred-promise-and-future-in-javascript)