# jQuery Deferred.then - failFilter argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am trying to get my head around jQuery deferred/promises (using v1.8+).

From reading the documentation, a `$.Deferred.then(...)` method accepts a `doneFilter` and a `failFilter` as arguments to execute, and it returns a promise, which we can use to chain as follows:

```
function doDefer() {
    var $defer = $.Deferred();

    doSomethingAsynchronous(
        function () {
            $defer.resolve();
        },
        function () {
            $defer.reject();
        }
    );

    return $defer.promise();
}

doDefer()
    .then(function () {
        return;
    }, function () {
        // second `then` not called
    })
    .then(function (b) {
        // `b` is undefined, since first `then` returned without a value.
    }, function () {
        // fail end
    });
```

Two questions:

1. Why does execution chain stop in `doDefer()`, if it hits the first `fail` function? As I understand, `then` returns a `$.Deferred.promise()` which is how the second `then` function is chained (and executes). The `then` doneFilter/function/callback in the first chain always returs(?) - so why/how does jQuery handle the `failFilter` differently?
2. Why does `then` return a `$.Deferred.promise()`, yet `done`/`always`/`fail`, etc. return a `$.Deferred`? What use would this be (and why does it differ to `then`)?

Comment: No, it works just fine. I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oy95nh47/1/ If you call "resolve", "done" is displayed twice. If you call "reject", "fail" is displayed twice.

Comment: Hmm, it does now. Is there a way I can quit the chain if `fail` is called at any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does execution chain stop in `doDefer()`, if it hits the first `fail` function? As I understand, `then` returns a promise which is how the second `then` function is chained (and executes). The `then` done callback in the first chain always returs(?) - so why/how does jQuery handle the `failFilter` differently?

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but there's two things you should know:

- `then(done, fail)` only ever executes one of its callbacks, depending on whether the promise they were chained on is fulfilled or rejected.
- [error handling is completely broken in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23744774/1048572). The callback does get called as expected, but the promise returned by the `.then(…)` call does not behave [Promises/A+ compliant](http://promisesaplus.org/). Wait for jQuery 3.0, use a proper promise library ([on top of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572)), or learn to live with it.

> Why does `then` return a `$.Deferred.promise()`

Because it's a promise that will resolve with the result of the respective callback. It's not a deferred that you can resolve yourself. See also [What are the differences between Deferred, Promise and Future in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6801283/1048572)

> …yet `done`/`always`/`fail`, etc. return a `$.Deferred`?

They don't. They just return the object they were called on, regardless whether it was a promise or a deferred.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this example, its work right:

```
function doDefer() {
    var $defer = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout( function(){
                doSomethingAsynchronous(
                    function ( value ) {
                        // func1 - value is a random number
                        $defer.resolve( value );
                    },
                    function () {
                        $defer.reject();
                    }
                );
            }, 1000 );

    return $defer.promise();
}

function doSomethingAsynchronous( func1, func2 ){
    // random number 0-10
    var random = Math.round( Math.random()*10 )
    if( random > 5 ){
        return func1.call( this, random );
    }else{
        return func2.call( this );
    }
}

doDefer().then(function ( value ) {
    // success
    // make double of random
    return value*2;
}, function () {
    // fail when random number < 5
})
.then(function (b) {
    // `b` is double of random number
    console.log(b);
}, function () {
    // fail end
});
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

the `failHandler` will stop execution like you said. The key is to look at the chain. A fail handler will only execute if the Promise it was chained to is rejected. Make sure you are looking at each link in the chain as a separate promise.

The chaining can be rewritten as follows.

```
dfd1 = doDefer();

dfd2 = dfd1.then( success1, fail1 );

dfd3 = dfd2.then( success2, fail2 );
```

in this example, `success1` will only be called if `dfd1` is resolved. If it is rejected, `fail1` wil be called instead and the chain will stop.

Likewise, `success2` will only be called if `dfd2` is resolved (in other words, `success1` returns a value or resolves a returned promise). The only way `fail2` gets executed, is if `dfd2` is rejected explicitly by `success1` (error bubbling does not work in jQuery's implementation).

tl;dr - fails don't chain and as @Bergi said, error handling is broken in jQuery