# Difference between Promise, Promise/A and Promise/A+

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise, es6-promise

I've read the Promise/A+ specification, but as far as I understand there are also such things as Promise/A and Promise. What is the difference between all of them? Are Promise and Promise/A specifications as well? If so, what's the difference? Sorry if the question is silly as I'm primary backend developer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Promise a specification as well?

No. That's just a term with a context-dependent meaning. See for example [What are the differences between Deferred, Promise and Future in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6801283/1048572) or [the Wikipedia entry on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) for possible definitions.

> Is Promise/A a specification as well?

Yes: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A

Why is it named *A*? Because there were [other approaches](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) as well.

> I've read the Promise/A+ specification. What is the difference between them?

You must have missed https://promisesaplus.com/differences-from-promises-a.