# Push function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a question and I don't know if it is possible to do that.

I have multiple files in .js who are in the same system (each function of every files is available inside the other files).

```
script_A.js
script_B.js
script_C.js
script_D.js
```

Inside my `script_A.js` I have a function `loadAllFunction()` and inside this function I put some function of the `script_B.js, script_C.js and script_D.js` that I want to load by default when I call `loadAllFunction()`.

So all works well like this but I am asking if it is possible to push the function I want inside `loadAllFunction()` directly since the files `script_B.js, script_C.js and script_D.js` ?

Something like for exemple :

`script_B.js` :

```
function loadScriptB() {....}
loadAllFunction(loadScriptB());
```

`script_C.js` :

```
function loadScriptC() {....}
loadAllFunction(loadScriptC());
```

`script_D.js` :

```
function loadScriptD() {....}
loadAllFunction(loadScriptD());
```

And then I call `loadAllFunction()` from my `script_A.js` for load all.

It is possible to do something like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use word ["defer"](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_script_defer.asp) in `<script>` command to load script file with `loadAllFunction()` after all other.

2) You should read [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801283/what-are-the-differences-between-deferred-promise-and-future-in-javascript). Depending of your task you can use Promise or Deferreds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I can understand to use promise with `script_A.js` for `loadAllFunction()`, but my question is more about the possibility to 'call / append' this function with another function since another script (script_B, C or D) like this `loadAllFunction(loadScriptC());` (from script_C.js)

Comment: Probably you release very strange logic in your application. Can your show more code?

Comment: Actually I just put every times all the functions I need to load (from all my scripts, A B C D) into the general function `loadAllFunction()` (who is in script_A), and I just asking me if another method was existing for charge  `loadAllFunction()` with all my functions from the other scripts (B C D), but it was more an question that I have, and I think it is not possible to do that .. Anyway thank you for your help :)