# Last value of an asynchronous function in loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, for-loop, google-chrome-extension, callback

I have this in a function:

```
for (i=0; i < toTranslateArray.length; i++)
{
    (function(i)
    {
        getTranslation(toTranslateArray[i],function(callback_result)
        {
            trans += callback_result;
        });         
    })(i);  
}
// code using last value of trans
```

I need to use last value of trans. I have seen a lot of examples but i just can`t make it work.
Another answers same with my problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696747/call-asynchronous-function-inside-for-loop)

Comment: Is the order in which you are concatenating the results relevant?

Comment: When you use `for-in`, there's no way to reliably know when you're at the last value, unless you count the properties beforehand. Is `toTranslateArray` an actual Array? If so, it becomes simpler, though you still shouldn't be using `for-in`, but rather a `for` statement.

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? Please show us your specific attempts otherwise we would need to refer you to that question with the same problem.

Comment: @Bergi yes they are relevant.

Comment: the last value of trans is the one that has at the end of the loop

Comment: Should be noted, as Bergi hinted at, that if it is an asynchronous function, you may not be able to guarantee the order of the results is what you expect.

Comment: @smotru: Then see [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) and notice that `getTranslation` is asynchronous.

Comment: @CrazyTrain yes it is an array. I would use a for then. I will show you my new code in few mins.

Comment: for more details here is my complete function: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214286/javascript-synchronous-functions-chrome-extension?noredirect=1#comment26730514_18214286)

Comment: I have edited my code. I just don`t understand how can i get the last value out of the for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard way to deal with asynchronous loops (see also [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)):

```
var results = [];
for (var count=0; count<toTranslateArray.length; count++) (function(i) {
    getTranslation(toTranslateArray[count], function(res) {
        results[i] = res;
        if (! --count) { // when all results are settled (count is back to zero)
            var trans = results.join("");
            // code using trans
        }
    });           
})(count);
```

Notice this will only execute the code when there was at least one item in the array.

Comment: Ah, I was just seconds away from posting, but with `.forEach()`. +1

Comment: You just saved me after 2 days on this problem .. I couldn`t understand closures :(