# How to break loop inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm doing kind of QA (Question/Answers) application using the Bluebird library. So here's the scenario:

1. User fill the form with answers for some number of questions (e.g 5 questions).
2. A question has more than 1 possible answer: "Question has many answers"
3. Answers are encrypted (bcrypt) on database using [node.bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/)
4. When looping through answers, if user answer matches, there's no need to continue checking the answer for that question.

So it's a common problem to solve when doing things synchronous, but I'm a little lost to do that async with promises.

Here's a sample of what I don't know how to proceed:

```
  .then(function(answers) {
    var compare = Promise.promisify(bcrypt.compare);
    // foreach answer, I need to check like this
    // compare(answer.password, user.password).then(function(match){
    //      if (match) break; <-- something like this
    //   })
  })
```

Comment: You may have to get the encrypted answer separately before the loop, and inside the callback start the loop and just do basic checking `(if hash == password) break;`

Comment: @tymeJV I think I can't do that, cause when I hash the password with bcrypt, a different value is generated from the database previously generated value... that's the reason why I need the bcrypt compare function... Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Don't have my bcrypt repo up in front of me but that sounds right - callback hell :\ - this post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214862/async-functions-inside-foreach-loops-with-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to call the `compare`s sequentially, this will do it:

```
.then(function(answers) {
    var compare = Promise.promisify(bcrypt.compare),
        i = 0;
    return Q(false).then(function checkNext(res) {
        return res ||
               i<answers.length && compare(answers[i++].password, user.password)
                                     .then(checkNext);
    });
})
```

It will "recursively" step trough the `answers` array, stopping on the first `true` result. To return the correct answer (instead of just `true` for "found") or `null` (if not found) like @Noseratio's code, you could use

```
    var i = 0, answer;
    return Q(false).then(function checkNext(res) {
        return res ? answer : (i<answers.length || null) && compare((answer = answers[i++]).password, user.password).then(checkNext);
    });
```

or better the more verbose

```
function next(i) {
    if (i < answers.length)
        return compare(answers[i].password, user.password).then(function(res) {
             return res ? answers[i] : next(i+1);
        });
    else
        return null;
}
return next(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution (untested) implements a state machine to simulate `foreach` loop. The `result` promise is resolved when the match has been found, or when there is no more answers to compare:

```
  .then(function(answers) {
    var result = new Promise();
    var i = 0;
    function nextStep() {
      if (i >= answer.length)
        result.resolve(null);
      else {
        var answer = answers[i];
        if (compare(answer.password, user.password).then(function(match) {
          if (match)
            result.resolve(answer);
          else {
            i++;
            nextStep(); // do the next step
          }
        })
      }
    }
    process.nextTick(nextStep); // do the first step asynchronously    
    return result; // return the result as a promise
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a simple solution:

```
let breakLoop = false
for (let answer of arr) {
  if (breakLoop) continue
  compare(answer.password, user.password)
    .then(match => {
      if (match) breakLoop = true
    })
    .catch(err => breakLoop = true)
}
```