# jQuery callback when 3 methods are finished?

Tags: jquery

I have 3  JS functions :

```
func1 ()
{
    $.ajax(...,callback1)
}


func2 ()
{
    $.ajax(...,callback2)
}


func3 ()
{
    $.ajax(...,callback3)
}
```

They are executed  like this :

```
func1();
func2();
func3();
```

Question how can I execute `mySummaryCallback()` after all 3 are `done` ?

NB

I could use a closure callback function which increase a value and then execute. but I can't touch the ajax callback functions. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911891/859154)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to do this for all your methods need to return the promise object back to the caller

```
func1() {
    return $.ajax(..., callback1)
}


func2() {
    return $.ajax(..., callback2)
}


func3() {
    return $.ajax(..., callback3)
}

$.when(func1(), func2(), func3()).done(function () {
    //all are success
}).fail(function(){
    //atleast one failed
}).always(function(){
    //all are completed
})
```

Comment: Your edit helped me.. so `when` signals when they all **resolved** and then they (all results) **filtered to one** callback  done/fail/always....right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes... the `always` is called in either case... along with `done` and `fail`

Comment: I guess always() will be fired even, e.g, only first deferred object failed, not waiting for all completed. This need more test thought

Answer (score 2):

Return promise interface, exposed by each ajax request, from your functions and use `$.when()` jquery method:

```
func1 ()
{
    return $.ajax(...,callback1)
}


func2 ()
{
    return $.ajax(...,callback2)
}


func3 ()
{
    return $.ajax(...,callback3)
}

$.when(func1(),func2(),func3()).done(/*callback*/);
```

Comment: Does the `When` signals when they  all  `complete` or `done` ?

Comment: when done (success), for complete use always() and for error use fail()

Comment: Yeah I know but where does it say that `when` signals when they all done ?  the docs says that it signal when it resloved.

Comment: It's fired when all deferred objects are success callback fired.

Comment: so my first comment is incorrect. I asked: **when** does the  `when` functions signals .

Comment: What are we talking about? Your first comment is a question, how can this be incorrect?

Comment: I meant : my assumption/question (my first comment) is incorrect. then `when` signals when they all resolved. and not when they all complete or done.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit `callbackN` functions directly, make a wrapper, for instance:

```
func2 ()
{
    $.ajax(..., function() {
        //call your callback here
        callback2();

        //increase your counter here once it's done ...
    });
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) in this situation

Answer (score 0):

One way is to synchronized all the Ajax calls and then you need to call your BigCallback

Otherwise you need to check what is the state(0- for request initiated, to 4) of the last Ajax then you can proceed according.